# Redirect in HttpPost Controller not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have this controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Compose(ComposeMessage composeMessage)
{
    var message = "";
    dynamic fbPost = new ExpandoObject();
    fbPost.message = composeMessage.Message;
    dynamic result = FBHelper.PostInFacebook(fbPost, associatedAccount.ProviderAccessToken);
    if (((IDictionary<String, object>)result).ContainsKey("error"))
    {
        Session["PostMessage"] = fbPost;
        var redirectUrl = FBHelper.GetLoginUrl("email,read_stream,publish_stream");
        //HttpContext.ClearError();
        //the below redirect does not work
        Redirect(redirectUrl);
        //message = "Posting to Facebook failed. \n";
    }
    else
    {
        message = "Posting to Facebook successful. \n";
    }
    return Json(new { success = message });
}
```

Here what I am trying to do basically is to Redirect to Facebook OAuth if my access token is expired.
But the code `Redirect(redirectUrl);` does not fire at all. My questions are

1. What is wrong with the code?
2. Why is redirect not firing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think its becouse [HttpPost] attribute. You can pass your url to client and the call navigate(), or window.location = myurl.

Comment: +1: i haven't thought about this. sounds like a dirty hack :)

Comment: @naveen mb just a little bit :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to return the redirect `ActionResult`:

```
return Redirect(redirectUrl);
```